# Convert yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z' to DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert this string `20120123T112804440Z` into **mysql `DATETIME`** format.

I did just this: 
`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20120123T112804440Z', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%fZ')`.

I do not know how to complete it.

Comment: What's the problem with that conversion? `INSERT INTO yourtable (column1) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('20120123T112804440Z', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%fZ'));` works fine if yourtable.column1 is datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20120123T112804440Z', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s')
```

**Result: 2012-01-23 11:28:04**

Answer (score 0):

just remember that by default DATETIME has zero digit after the seconds and you are trying to convert something contains micro seconds ...28:04.440

you need to convert to `DATATIME(3)` which has three digit after seconds.

otherwise you statement looks fine